# Remote Wireless 4CH Switch On/Off - Data PIN Network Cable

Tags: switches, relay, wireless, network

*Planning Stage*

I'm in the planning stages of making a wireless on/off switch that will basically **cut off** pin 6 on a network cable. I know little about electronics and I've attempted to learn as much as I can before coming here, so bare with me If I make no sense.

*Wireless Switch*

I purchased a wireless receiver 4ch remote switch which has VT OUT STATUS(No idea what this is), D0, D1, D2, D3, GND, +5v. I believe D0, 1D1, D2 and D3 represent +v5 output when triggered which would then complete a circuit to output to a LED or 5v component.

*The Problem*

It is my understanding the current way this receiver works is that it completes a voltage circuit therefor outputting 5v and most likely useless to turn on a LED. However, I need the circuit to be constantly on until toggled off. From what I learned reading various sources I've learned some what about relays but unable to find out if complete a circuit other than one that has power running through it. Basically all I want to do is turn off PIN 6 on a data network cable when pressed.

*The Question*

Using the current setup what do I need to be able to disable communications on PIN6 of a network cable (please note that I have PCB ports and everthing, Just need some guildance in accordance with turning the wireless +5v switch into a block data switch.

Would this work?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcHjBC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What about a transmitter?

Answer (score 2):

The output will almost certainly drive an LED so connect one up via a 220 ohm resistor and convince yourself it works. The relay schematic you drew appears correct but you have to interface a relay to the receiver and this might require more current than the receiver is capable of. In short you may need to use a transistor between receiver and relay.

Answer (score 0):

VT Status Out is the Valid Transmit indicator and it shows that the received data is valid. You assert the data on the D0-D3 pins then when VT goes high, it indicates the data asserted is valid.

Here is a good description (link to document follows):

"When the DS enters Decoder Mode, it checks the state of the DIN line. If
it is high, the P_SEL line is checked to set which protocol is used and the
decoder receives the data. It compares the address in the received packet
to its local address lines. If they match, the data is stored and a second
packet is received. With the Holtek® protocol, the decoder compares the
two packets. If they match, the received data bits are output on the data
lines and the VT line is pulled high. This protocol compares each packet
with the previous one looking for a match. The serial protocol requires
two matching packets for initial activation, then updates the lines on each
subsequent packet. The DS then looks for the next packet on the DIN line.
With the Holtek® protocol, once no valid data is received (there is a
mismatch of address, data, or bit timings), the Data and VT lines are pulled
low and the DS goes to sleep until DIN is pulled high. The Serial protocol
holds the output states until a 130ms timer runs out."

https://www.linxtechnologies.com/resources/data-guides/lical-edc-ds001.pdf

Other chips may handle this differently, but the overall concept is the same.